# Heated Snow Shovel Patent

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US4034489](https://www.google.com/patents/US4034489)

Is this patent abandoned?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter as it would have expired naturally in the early 1990's. Strangely enough this is the first US patent I've been unable to access in the [US Public Pair site](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair).